# How to make such function `shouldBeRight :: Either a b -> IO b`?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make such two functions as below in order to get the "Right" value or the "Just" value. But can't compile, why?

```
shouldBeRight :: (Show a) => Either a b -> IO b
shouldBeRight (Left a) =
  throwIO $ concat ["should be Right value but wasn't, because:", show a]
shouldBeRight (Right b) = return b

shouldBeJust :: Maybe a -> IO a
shouldBeJust Nothing = throwIO "should be Just value but was Nothing"
shouldBeJust (Just a) = return a
```

Here are the errors:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘throwIO’
      prevents the constraint ‘(GHC.Exception.Exception
                                  e0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘e0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        30 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
      In an equation for ‘shouldBeJust’:
          shouldBeJust Nothing
            = throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
   |
23 | shouldBeJust Nothing = throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...

    • Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from the literal ‘"should be Just value but is nothing"’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Data.String.IsString
                                  e0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘e0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance a ~ Char => Data.String.IsString [a]
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String’
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘throwIO’, namely
        ‘"should be Just value but is nothing"’
      In the expression: throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
      In an equation for ‘shouldBeJust’:
          shouldBeJust Nothing
            = throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
   |
23 | shouldBeJust Nothing = throwIO "should be Just value but is nothing"
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This seems to be a rather confusing way of saying that the argument of `throwIO` needs to be an instance of `Exception` class, which `String` doesn't seem to be. Or at least the [signature](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:throwIO) of `throwIO` suggests such interpretation.

Comment: I see. Using `error` instead works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the type of exception that you're trying to `throwIO`.

Judging from the error messages, you probably have `-XOverloadedStrings` enabled, which means that string literals, e.g. `"abcd"`, don't have a definitive type, but can take on whatever type is expected, provided that there is an `IsString` instance for it. The most frequently used string types are `String` and `Text`, but there are others, and you can also make your own.

On the other hand, the function [`throwIO`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.6/base-4.12.0.0/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO)`:: Exception e => e -> IO a` also doesn't specify any specific type: it takes any type `e`, as long as there is an `Exception` instance for it.

So the compiler kind of doesn't know which types to pick. There is no basis for picking anything.

The "normal" way this should be solved is to create your own exception type and give it an `Exception` instance, like this:

```
data MyConversionException = NotJust | NotRight String deriving (Typeable, Show)

instance Exception MyConversionException
```

And then throw that:

```
shouldBeRight (Left a) = throwIO $ NotRight (show a)

...

shouldBeJust Nothing = throwIO NotJust
```

If you really want your exception to display that specific text when it happens, you can always give it a custom `Show` instance:

```
instance Show MyConversionException where
    show NotJust = "should be Just value but was Nothing"
    show (NotRight leftValue) = "should be Right value but wasn't, because:" ++ leftValue
```

Alternatively, if you just want a quick-n-dirty solution, you can use the [`error`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.6/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:error) function, which generates a runtime exception, much like `throwIO`, except its type is pure, so it can be used outside IO as well:

```
shouldBeJust Nothing = error "should be Just value but was Nothing"
```

Comment: Why even mention `error` in an `IO` context where there's a much cleaner mechanism available?

Comment: @dfeuer Two reasons: (1) judging by the rest of the code, it is very possible that the OP was looking for a quick fix, and (2) `error` was already suggested in the comments, and the OP chose to go with it.